PC reboots automatically
Sometimes my computer suddenly turns off without alert or even a shutdown screen and boots back up again automatically. It can go weeks without this happening, but on days when it happens, it happens a lot.
I'm running Windows 10 on an AMD A8-5500B 3.20 GHz APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics and 8GB of RAM.
I ran a memory diagnoses and it says my memory is fine.
I checked the event viewer for anything relevant and there is nothing before the power off time, however, I find this message after it boots back on:

"The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."

from Kernel-Power


Perform Windows repairs (DISM and SFC) or reinstall Windows, keeping files. 2. To see if it's a hardware issue,, boot from USB, e.g., Win RE, Win PE or Ubuntu Live, after the issue occurs. If that works flawlessly for a day or two, look to the HDD/SSD. If it crashes anyway, then almost certainly it's hardware -- anything from a loose connector to failing part.


No, It also happened on another Windows installation, I'll try with Linux, keep in mind that I can't really predict when/if it happens, so I'll just keep daily driving Linux till it happens,  or not... Windows suck anyways

Intermittent problems are a pain to diagnose. Some issues are known as a Hesienbug: when you make a change to detect the issue (e.g., add exception handling), it disappears as long as you are observing.
